# QGIS slow when working with Form View

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have several features on a layer.

I want to edit each one and move on to the next.

I click Open Attribute Table -> Form View

Whenever I type a character in a field a progress bar runs in the task bar (windows 11) under the main QGIS window and the screen freezes. It's like it's continually trying to update the project.

This doesn't happen if I use the Edit feature form in identifier view.

What can I do to make the Form View usable? It's completely unusable in the current state.